# Why did the 'ie' survive through the many German orthography reforms?

Tags: orthography, german

German orthography is now much simpler than ever and there are now far less redundancies than there ever was. One thing that has drawn my attention lately is the fact that never after an 'ie' in a word comes a double consonant (e. g. 'ff' 'ck' 'tt' etc.), in fact, whenever I see that (in surnames or town names) it seems pretty archaic to me. A single consonant after an 'i' is almost always interpreted as long (except for prepositions like 'in', 'bis', 'mit'). So that suggests we could remove the 'e' and still be able to read and pronounce everything correctly  (for example 'Schiff', 'schif' instead of 'Schiff', 'schief'). The same is true to a less extent for vowels followed by an 'h' ('Ban' could be pronounced like 'Bahn' without problem). Note that I'm not talking about the word endings (those should pretty much stay the same in case a plural or conjugations depend on them like 'Kuh' 'Kühe').

Has there ever been a debate on this topic? What where the reasons to keep it? Are they considering anything about it?
I'm not asking why we aren't changing it right now. That's a whole other discussion, which involves far more issues than a simple 'ie'.

Comment: *Schiff* and *schief* are not pronounced the same by native speakers.  I know you're proposing one or the other, not both, but frankly removing a repeated consonant would be very lossy, even without also changing *-ie-* to *-i-*.  So better to omit that from this question.

Comment: I never said they're pronounced the same. Thanks, I guess you are right, because then there would be the problem with the words of Latin origin, and you can't really mess with them (like put 'h' after vowels or anything). The only thing that seems to be bit of a problem here are prepositions and articles, which could have actually worked out considering the homophones "das" and "dass" (and still can in my opinion).

Comment: *bin* in many accents too.

Comment: Is there perhaps a question of intonation?  Even Latinish words like *Turnier* and *protokollieren* normally carry stress on *-ie-*, which is not the case with *-i-*.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd say _protokollieren_ could still be pronounced the way it is right now without the 'e'. The problem is, many words of foreign origin aren't stressed in a way that is intuitive for the German speakers (except when there are special patters, e. g. affixes or word endings). So the -ier could stay for that matter, but even then, there are examples contradicting that, like _Dinosaurier_. And yeah, I forgot to mention _bin_.

Comment: *-iren* to *-ieren* was a conscious decision and a relatively recent one, perhaps it's not the best example.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It seems to have happened in the first reform. Also, the suffix _-nis_ is another exception where it would've made more sense to use _-niss_. I guess the orthography is a bit too messy on other parts to allow us not to use a second indicator for long/short vowels. So in order to completely get rid of the indicators after vowels, we'd have to make suffixes, affixes, prepositions etc. exceptions (even though they are already exceptions somehow). But I still would like to know if they've ever considered doing that.

Comment: Re *they*: In the end anyway these things are only somewhat centrally mandated.  Major (and minor) publications can and do occasionally diverge from the prescriptions for Rechtschreibung (and even language) of the relevant regimes, Duden etc.

Comment: Possibly, but that wouldn't be the best thing to happen either.

Comment: As a German native speaker I wouldn't pronounce `Bahn` and `Ban` the same way. (Words like Bandit that start with `Ban` don't have `Ban` pronounced the same way as `Bahn`)

Comment: If you want to know why it’s usually written _ie_ (or _ieh_) instead of (rare) _ih_ (like _ah, äh, eh, oh, öh, uh, üh_) or _ii_ (like rare _aa, oo_ and _ee_ and as in Finnish) or _ij / ÿ_ (typographic variants of the former, similar to Dutch) or _í_ (like _é_ in gallicisms or as in Czech) or _ī_ (as in text-book Latin) or _î_ (as in Hepburn Japanese) or _y_ (as in Polish I think) then it’s a very different question from why it’s _ieC_ : _iC_ : _iCC_. The latter is basically the same for _VhC_ / _VVC_ : _VC_ : _VCC_.

Comment: @Christian Ok, but that's just because the stress is not on 'a' (another example would be _Banane_). There is nothing to indicate the accented syllable and so the vowel length, which is a whole other topic on its own. Would you pronounce all _Bahn_, _Ban_ and _Bann_ differently (assuming they are separate one syllable, _German_  words)?

Comment: @user3482545 : Yes, instinctually I think I would pronounce all of the three differently. I'm not completely sure about "Ban" given that the only usages as a German word are loan words from Thai or Croatia but if I plug the pronunciation of Bahn or Bann into Banane it doesn't feel right.

Comment: According to Wiktionary the first 'a' in _Banane_ should be pronounced like the 'a' in _Mann_, and the second one like the 'a' in _Bahn_. Are you sure they don't fit in just because you somehow try to keep the stress (which is on the _Ba_ in separate words, but on_na_ in _Banane_). I suppose it also depends on the dialect/different native accents, so I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some principles when you ever attempt a spelling reform—one of them is keeping the tradition of reading and writing intact (in German, the term *behutsam* was used when the latest spelling reforms starting in 1998 were introduced). There was lots of outrage and resistance against those reforms much underestimated by the politicians driving it forwards.

Well-established spellings cannot be arbitrarily normalised or even be recreated from first principles in an already literate society. This is the reason why the German orthography sticks to the *ie* spelling (which denoted a diphthong in Middle High German that is preserved in the Bavarian dialect where "lieb" is still pronounced *liab*).

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answers the questions, which, like I also suspected, is because it's too big of a change for people to accept, which I  understand considering I was being realistic from the beginning (I had already heard people being unhappy with 'f' replacing 'ph' in some places). I also didn't know there are still differences in dialects concerning 'ie'. I'm going to mark this as the right answer, unless someone else has some useful sources to share.

Answer (score 2):

The sounds "i" and "ie" are not the same; "ie" is basically a long "i". The German spelling remembers the pronunciation. The digraph "ie" plays exactly the same role as the long (acuted) "í" or "ý" in Czech language (or other Baltic and Slavic languages using the Czech diacritics and the Latin alphabet) whose pronunciation differs from the simple "i" or "y".

To replace "ie" by "i" would mean that the pronunciation in German is no longer determined by the spelling – a huge sacrifice.

Completely analogously, the German digraphs "ah" and "eh" create the long "á", "é" different from the simple short "a", "e".

If a reform should take place, German should use "á,é,í,ú,č,š,f,v" instead of "ah,eh,ie,uh,tsch,sch,v,w", and there are a few other replacements that would simplify the German spelling. I have actually written down some more detailed plans for this reform. ;-)

Comment: I didn't imply at all that 'ie' and 'i' are the same. My point here is, there are mostly_two_ indicators of long/short vowels in German words, one that comes after the vowel (e. g. 'e' in 'ie' or 'h' in 'ah' and 'eh') and one in the consonant following the vowel (double consonants). So in case we get rid of 'e', we'd _still_ be able to know which vowel is represented vowel based on whether or not there is a double consonant after it. The same could probably apply to 'ah', etc., but is a bit less obvious, so I wouldn't insist on anything about those.  I hope it's clear now what I mean by that.

Comment: Even if it's true that the double consonant always comes after "i" without "ie", wouldn't it be better to change it to a simple consonant? ;-) So spell it Schif, Schief?

Comment: Yeah, I did think of that originally, but then you'd have to change many vowels in words that are not of Germanic origin, because in many of those "i" is _not_ followed by a double consonant and it does mean a long vowel. 'ie', on the other hand, is never followed by a double consonant (anywhere, except maybe old texts), so that would be definitely a better approach, in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's very disputable whether the "i" in these foreign words is pronounced (in the original language) closer to "i" or "ie" in German. Even if you pick e.g. the supermarket chain Lidl, in Czech, we actually do pronounce it Liedel. Both "i" and "í" is being transcripted to German as "i", so it's ambiguous whether it actually means "i" or "ie" sound. The same applies to words from many other Slavic etc. languages.

Comment: Maybe, but _Lidl_'s a surname, so you can't really do much about it. In the case of words of Latin/Greek origin, it's pretty clear whether a vowel is short or long, I'd say, based on whether there is a double consonant following it, I don't know about the original pronunciation though.